# Halting postback, manually executing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, postback

My main page is a registration form with a Model. When the user clicks the submit button, the model validates and posts. However, I am in need of a step in between that forces the user to agree to some terms and fine print.

Originally, I was thinking that I would carry the model into a second confirmation page and then move onto a third ActionResult that saved the information.

Second, I thought of just hiding the main DIV and then showing a second DIV that the agreements "live" in and then post back. But I'm not sure how I would validate the model before showing the second DIV and THEN post the form.

Comment: why not start with the agreement page and if the user clicks on 'agree' then redirect to your registration page (phpbb had/has this form of agreement acceptance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make an extra call to validate the model if the user might reject your terms and fine print.  I think you should either do what @Daniel recommends or if you must do it this way, post your model, get the validation back, show your fine print and then post the form again to a different action to save.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include the fine print and terms (and corresponding checkbox) as part of the registration form? That's how it's done pretty much everywhere, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. There are some preview boxes and quite a few conditions to accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="myForm">
...
<input type="button" id="formSubmit">
</form>
<div id="agreement"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#agreement").hide();
}):

$("#formSubmit").click(function(){
$("#agreement").show();
//ur logic to check if the user agree or disagree
$.ajax({
type:POST,
data:"formdata"
url:"/your/url"
success:function(){

}


});
});
</script>
```